# Cannot delete Azure Active Directory Tenant

Tags: azure, entra-id

I'm attempting to delete an unused Azure Active Directory Tenant.

All initial checks have passed:

[image]

However, when I click "Delete", I get a popup saying "Unable to delete tenant.  Known issues exist where some enterprise applications are not capable to delete within the portal.":

[image]

I have clicked the link in the popup, which takes me to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/directory-delete-howto#remove-enterprise-apps-that-you-cant-delete) page, where it directs you to use Azure Powershell functions to ensure you have no Enterprise applications still attached to the tenant.  I've gone completely through that process to no avail.  There are no enterprise applications attached to the tenant, there are no users in the tenant except a global administrator account that I'm using to attempt the deletion.

As far as I can see, I've completed every action necessary, but still cannot delete the tenant.  I have a separate tenant already configured as the default, and have moved subscriptions and all resources, etc., to it.

I deleted my Twitter accounts last year, and have no intention of asking Azure's twitter support for help since that platform is dead to me.

Any suggestions on what I should do?